# Отметить в датафрейм время кратное 5 ти

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Каким образом для `df['Time']` можно сделать столбик `df['Time2']=0`, в котором каждые 5 или 10 минут (допустим 5) будет обозначение, что сейчас 5-я минута пошла?

```
df = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
df.columns = ['Date','Time','Ampl']
```

Пример
Было:

```
Date        Time    Ampl
20120217    133900  79.28
20120217    134000  79.29
20120217    134100  79.28
20120217    134200  79.29
20120217    134300  79.28
20120217    134400  79.28
20120217    134500  79.26
20120217    134600  79.3
20120217    134700  79.3
```

Стало:

```
Date        Time    Ampl     Time2   
20120217    133900  79.28    0
20120217    134000  79.29    1
20120217    134100  79.28    0
20120217    134200  79.29    0
20120217    134300  79.28    0
20120217    134400  79.28    0
20120217    134500  79.26    1
20120217    134600  79.3     0
20120217    134700  79.3     0
```

То есть, когда было значение 0,5,10...55 минут, в `df['Time2']` пишется 1.

[Файл](http://file.sampo.ru/sskn5v/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Советую парсить дату и время в единственный столбец как дату/время:

```
df = pd.read_csv("2.csv", parse_dates={"Timestamp": ["Date", "Time"]})
# NOTE: ----------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

получим:

```
In [182]: df.head()
Out[182]:
            Timestamp   Ampl
0 2012-02-17 13:39:00  79.28
1 2012-02-17 13:40:00  79.29
2 2012-02-17 13:41:00  79.28
3 2012-02-17 13:42:00  79.29
4 2012-02-17 13:43:00  79.28

In [183]: df.dtypes
Out[183]:
Timestamp    datetime64[ns]
Ampl                float64
dtype: object
```

теперь со столбцом `Timestamp` можно работать как с `datetime`:

```
df["Time2"] = df["Timestamp"].dt.minute.mod(5).eq(0).astype("int8")
```

результат:

```
In [185]: df
Out[185]:
             Timestamp   Ampl  Time2
0  2012-02-17 13:39:00  79.28      0
1  2012-02-17 13:40:00  79.29      1
2  2012-02-17 13:41:00  79.28      0
3  2012-02-17 13:42:00  79.29      0
4  2012-02-17 13:43:00  79.28      0
5  2012-02-17 13:44:00  79.28      0
6  2012-02-17 13:45:00  79.26      1
7  2012-02-17 13:46:00  79.30      0
8  2012-02-17 13:47:00  79.30      0
9  2012-02-17 13:48:00  79.31      0
10 2012-02-17 13:49:00  79.30      0
11 2012-02-17 13:50:00  79.31      1
12 2012-02-17 13:51:00  79.30      0
13 2012-02-17 13:52:00  79.30      0
14 2012-02-17 13:53:00  79.31      0
15 2012-02-17 13:54:00  79.30      0
16 2012-02-17 13:55:00  79.30      1
17 2012-02-17 13:56:00  79.30      0
18 2012-02-17 13:57:00  79.30      0
19 2012-02-17 13:58:00  79.30      0
20 2012-02-17 13:59:00  79.28      0
21 2012-02-17 14:00:00  79.28      1
22 2012-02-17 14:01:00  79.26      0
23 2012-02-17 14:02:00  79.25      0
24 2012-02-17 14:03:00  79.23      0

In [186]: df.dtypes
Out[186]:
Timestamp    datetime64[ns]
Ampl                float64
Time2                  int8
dtype: object
```

Comment: А можете подсказать как после всех операций вернуть Timestamp, разбив на Date и Time

Comment: @ssoop, Date: `df["Timestamp"].dt.floor("D")`, Time: `df["Timestamp"].dt.time` или `df["Timestamp"].dt.strftime("%H%M%S")`, если время нужно без двоеточий

Answer (score 3):

С учетом того, что в столбце Time у вас не время, а целочисленное значение, можно сделать так:

```
df["Time2"] = (~(df["Time"]%500).astype(bool)).astype(int)
```

получите df:

```
        Date    Time   Ampl  Time2
0   20120217  133900  79.28      0
1   20120217  134000  79.29      1
2   20120217  134100  79.28      0
3   20120217  134200  79.29      0
4   20120217  134300  79.28      0
5   20120217  134400  79.28      0
6   20120217  134500  79.26      1
7   20120217  134600  79.30      0
8   20120217  134700  79.30      0
9   20120217  134800  79.31      0
10  20120217  134900  79.30      0
11  20120217  135000  79.31      1

и т. д.
```